# Switch language of labels in Mapbox studio based on users locale

Tags: mapbox-studio

Is there an easy way to change all the map labels to use the users locale instead of a fixed locale. In Mapbox studio the default layers are set to `{name_en}`. Does that mean that each langugage needs its own Map-Style, or is there an API to change the language?

[image: Mapbox studio label language]